# GitHub: How to reopen a pull request

Tags: git, github

I opened a PR with a commit(commitA) and waiting for approve, but I accidentally pushed a wrong commit(commitB) to GitHub, and the wrong commit(commitB) was synchronised automatically to the PR. So I decided to close the PR and deleted the wrong commit(commitB). Meanwhile, I found a bug in the commitA, so I made a new commit(commitC) to fix the bug and push it to my own fork.

Now the commit recored in my own fork is ... -> commitA -> commitC, and the commit record in the closed PR is commitA -> commitB.

The question is how to reopen the PR with the correct commits? Should I open a new PR?

Comment: Was the pull request from a branch or from a fork?

Comment: @MartinGottweis from a fork

Comment: Then just create a new pull request the same way you created the first one.

Comment: Why commits in the PR is not synchronized with the fork?

Comment: There is **Reopen Pull Request** on comment section in Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset index in you branch `git reset --soft origin/master` – it will reset your commit history without losing changes in files.

Commit changes again with `git commit -am "fix the bug"` and push it again with `--force` key.

As a result your PR will contain only one commit in history.